# Weird Eclipse behaviour when tring to override a method

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, overriding

I have this two classes, `Dog` and `Beagle` that extends `Dog`.

```
class Dog {
    protected String bark() {return "woof "; }
}
class Beagle extends Dog {
    private String bark() { return "arf "; }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog[] dogs = {new Dog(), new Beagle()};
        for(Dog d : dogs)
            System.out.print(d.bark());
    }
}
```

When I'm using any other editor rather than Eclipse, the above code it does not even compile. I'm getting this error:

> Attempting to assign weaker access privileges to bark() method in
>   Beagle class.

You can also see this behavior [here](https://ideone.com/wJh6yd).

If I use Eclipse Indigo (Version: 3.7.2), this code compiles fine and the output is: `woof woof`.

Please make me understand which one is correct and why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code shouldn't pass compilation in eclipse either. Perhaps you are running an earlier version of your code.

Comment: I get an error message in eclipse too: `Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Dog`. Clean your Project and rebuild it. I guess than the Problem is not longer reprduceable

Comment: @Eran I'm using `Version: 3.7.2`. Is this version so old?

Comment: Doesn't compile in Eclipse Neon.2 using Java 1.8.0_102

Comment: Eclipse 3.7.2 is very old, 4.6.3 is the current release with 4.7.0 coming by the end of the month.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 I will update with the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other IDE's seeing it  as parent method and giving you the correct error message.

Coming to eclipse (*that's weird from eclipse side*), since there is no `@ovveride` annotation it is completely treating that as a new method in child, hence no error. If you place `@ovveride` annotation in child, you see the same error as other IDE's.

It is the same reason that you getting `woof woof` twice, as it is calling the same method from parent twice as it is assuming you are not calling the new method created from child.

To avoid the confusion it is always recommend that to use the @ovveride annotation while overriding methods.

Comment: I don't know about older versions of eclipse but the posted code does not compile in Neon.2

Comment: @JonK Agreed. Neon giving error but look which version OP is using. (Indigo I believe)

Comment: Yes, i'm using Indigo and also an older version. When using `@Override
annotation' i'm having the expected behaviour. Now, completely understood. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IoanaP. You are welcome :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

> If I use Eclipse, this code compiles fine and the output is: woof woof.

I dont think so, you are not allowed to reduce the visibility the method of bark

it must be

```
@Override
protected String bark() {
    return "arf ";
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
private String bark() {
    return "arf ";
}
```

after that modification then Begle is correctly overriden the bark method, so the output must be:

> woof arf

---

side note:

> Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Comment: Thank you for your explication!

Answer (score 1):

You have not written `@Override` annotation in child class. So compiler is considering it to be a different method rather than overridden method.

While overriding we can increase the visibility but we cannot decrease it. So make your overridden method to be `protected` or `public`.

Comment: Thank you for your explication!

Comment: @IoanaP. You are welcome !!